# Question regarding 404 "update" call using node, express and pug

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404, pug

I am building a simple app using node, express and pug. We are working to store "bycicles" data. We have a create/view and delete views examples but were asked to implement the update function given the examples.

I can load the specified bycicle data in the form, but, when pressing send as to update the written data for the bycicle a 404 error loads instead, Im veeeery new to this webpage programming and have no idea how this is happening, so I'm asking for any help in understanding the issue.

I used the create.pug example to build my update.pug view.
In the form I am a bit unsure if I should put (action='bicicletas/update') or ('bicicletas/'+bici.id+'/update')
I will post it here (the update.pug):

```
extends ../layout
block content
    a(href='/bicicletas') Volver

    br
    br
    br
    h1 Editar bicicleta
    br
    br


    // form(action='bicicletas/'+bici.id+'/update',method='post')

    form(action='bicicletas/update', method='post')
        label(for='id') ID:
        input#id(type='text' name='id' value=bici.id )
        br
        select(name='color', id='', required)
            each val in ['--select--','Blanco' , 'Negro' , 'Rojo','Verde']
                option=val
        br
        select(name='modelo', id='', required)
            each val in ['--select--','Ruta' , 'Cross' , 'Montian','Turismo']
                option=val
        br
        label(for='lat') Latitud:
        input#id(type='text' name='lat' value= bici.ubicacion[0] )
        br
        label(for='lng') Longitud:
        input#id(type='text' name='lng' value= bici.ubicacion[1]  )
        br
        br
        input.btn(type='submit' name='OK' )
```

I have succesfully completed the "get" function but the "post" function is the one that's throwing the 404.

In my routes > bycicles I have set up my routes, as indicated by the example, in this way:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bicicletaController = require("../controllers/bicicleta");

router.get("/", bicicletaController.list);
router.get("/:id/show", bicicletaController.show);
router.get("/create", bicicletaController.create_get);
router.post("/create", bicicletaController.create_post);
router.get("/:id/update", bicicletaController.update_get);
router.post("/:id/update", bicicletaController.update_post);
router.post("/:id/delete", bicicletaController.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

In a controllers folder I added an example bycicle script in which I created an update_get and an update_post using the other ones as reference

```
const Bicicleta = require("../models/bicicleta");
exports.list = function (re, res) {
  res.render("bicicletas/index", { bicis: Bicicleta.allBicis });
};
exports.show = function (req, res) {
  var bici = Bicicleta.findById(req.params.id);
  res.render("bicicletas/show", { bici });
};
exports.create_get = function (req, res) {
  res.render("bicicletas/create");
};
exports.create_post = function (req, res) {
  var bici = new Bicicleta(req.body.id, req.body.color, req.body.modelo);
  bici.ubicacion = [req.body.lat, req.body.lng];
  Bicicleta.add(bici);
  res.redirect("/bicicletas");
};
exports.delete = function (req, res) {
  Bicicleta.removeById(req.body.id);
  res.redirect("/bicicletas");
};

exports.update_get = function (req, res) {
  var bici = Bicicleta.findById(req.params.id);
  res.render("bicicletas/update", { bici });
};

exports.update_post = function (req, res) {
  var bici = new Bicicleta(req.body.id, req.body.color, req.body.modelo);
  bici.ubicacion = [req.body.lat, req.body.lng];
  Bicicleta.update(req.body);
  res.redirect("/bicicletas");
};
```

I created a bycicle model in which I added the update using a similar method to the preexisting removebyID function, using a splice to replace the bycicle.

```
let Bicicleta = function (id, color, modelo, ubicacion) {
    this.id = id;
    this.color = color;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
  };
  Bicicleta.prototype.toString = function () {
    return `id: ${this.id} | color: ${this.color}`;
  };
  
  Bicicleta.allBicis = [];

  Bicicleta.add = function (aBici) {
    Bicicleta.allBicis.push(aBici);
  };
  Bicicleta.findById = function (aBiciId) {
    var aBici = Bicicleta.allBicis.find((x) => x.id == aBiciId);
    if (aBici) return aBici;
    else throw new Error(`No existe una Bicicleta con el id: ${aBiciId}`);
  };
  
  Bicicleta.removeById = function (aBiciId) {
    var aBici = Bicicleta.findById(aBiciId);
    for (let i = 0; i < Bicicleta.allBicis.length; i++) {
      if (Bicicleta.allBicis[i].id == aBiciId) {
        Bicicleta.allBicis.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  Bicicleta.update = function (aBici) {
    var aBiciOld = Bicicleta.findById(aBici.id);
    for (let i = 0; i < Bicicleta.allBicis.length; i++) {
      if (Bicicleta.allBicis[i].id == aBiciOld.id) {
        Bicicleta.allBicis.splice(i, 1, aBici);
        break;
      }
    }
  };
```

And as I just mentioned I'm very confused as why the 404 error.
The console doesn't give any hints, just the error handler.

```
 NotFoundError: Not Found
    at E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\app.js:29:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (E:\2021-2\Topicos_Ingenieria_Software\LAB_01\redBicicletas\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

All help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the value of the `action` attribute in your `<FORM>` to "/update".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake.
The part in the form

```
form(action='bicicletas/update', method='post')
```

should really be

```
form.inline(action=`/bicicletas/${bici.id}/update`, method='post')
```

That fixed the 404 error.